# Convert Factor to Date with Years of Two Digits

Tags: r, date, type-conversion, as.date

I need your help in this:
I have a date of birth column in CSV file and the type is “factor”. I would like to convert the type into “date”.

The column data:

```
8-Dec-09  
8-Dec-12
8-Dec-14 
8-Dec-42 
8-Dec-49 
8-Dec-53 
8-Dec-61  
8-Dec-62
```

The years of the first three rows are: 2009, 2012, and 2014.

While the years for the rest are: 1942, 1949, 1953, 1961, and 1962

When used the `as.Date`, and tried to display the column, I received the message:

> "< table of extent 0 >."

First Attempt:

```
Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH <- as.Date(Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

Second Attempt:

```
Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH <- as.Date(Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Third Attempt:

```
Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH <- as.Date(Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH, format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
```

Fourth Attempt:

```
Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH <- as.Date(Patient$DATE_OF_BIRTH, format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

In the previous attempts, unfortunately the output I got was:

> "< table of extent 0 >"

I expect the output:

to be 8-Dec-09 to be 8-Dec-2009 OR 8/Dec/2009 and

the output of 8-Dec-62 to be 8-Dec-1962 OR 8/Dec/1962 or

to remain the same 8-Dec-09 and 8-Dec-62 but the column type to be date instead of factor.

I highly appreciate if you suggest the conversion without using R packages since I am working in environment where the packages are hard to be installed. But if there's no way, please suggest whatever works.

Comment: A two digit year is `%y`, not `%Y`.  See `?strptime` for the percent codes.

Comment: You need to match the date in the `format` argument literally. `%x` matches the digits and words of dates and everything else should be matched by you. Obviously, if there is no time in your date, you should forego `%H:%M`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I tried using %y and it gives me <NA>

Comment: @roman-luštrik I removed %H:%M but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` library of the `tidyverse` may help, specifically the `dmy()` function (converts day-month-year strings to dates):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

example <- c("8-Dec-09")
example_asdate <- dmy(example)
head(example_asdate)
#[1] "2009-12-08" 

Patient <- Patient %>% mutate(DATE_OF_BIRTH = dmy(DATE_OF_BIRTH))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, but keep in mind that this is locale specific. If it doesn't work for you, you may need to change locale for the conversion.

```
> as.Date("8-Dec-09", format = "%d-%b-%y")
[1] "2009-12-08"
```

If you look at the documentation (`?strptime`), you will notice this about `%y`:

> Year without century (00–99). On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed
>   by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19 – that is the behaviour specified by the 2004
>   and 2008 POSIX standards, but they do also say ‘it is expected that in
>   a future version the default century inferred from a 2-digit year will
>   change’.